# counting number of command line variable in bash

Tags: bash, unix

I am trying to make a usage function which validates number of arguments, i tried below code but if condition is always false even when i provided three arguments. Also `echo $#` also produces 0.

```
#!/bin/bash
programname=$0
function usage {

    if [ $# -ne 3 ]
    then
      echo "Usage: $programname filename LogFile milestoneFile"
      echo $#
      exit 1
    fi
}
usage
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code, function `usage` counts **function's** arguments with `$#`, not program's arguments.

You can rewrite like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
programname=$0
function usage {

    if [ $1 -ne 3 ]
    then
      echo "Usage: $programname filename LogFile milestoneFile"
      echo $1
      exit 1
    fi
}
usage $#
```

Now you call your function with 1 argument, contains the count of arguments for your script. `$1` in function is equal `$#` in script (equal 0 when you just run `./script.sh`, equal 3 if you run `./script.sh one two three` etc.)

Comment: Or, without modifying the OP's function, `usage "$@"` to pass the script's arguments to the function.

Answer (score 4):

Currently, you are checking the `usage()` function arguments, not the whole program's.

I would write it like this:

```
programname=$0

function usage {
      echo "Usage: $programname filename LogFile milestoneFile"
      echo $1
}
if [ $# -ne 3 ]
then
    #Call the function with `$#` arg, or you will get `echo 0` every time inside of the function`
    usage $#
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: This is the superior approach. There are other instances where you might want to display a usage message (such as if one of the arguments isn't an allowed value). Decoupling the test for displaying the message from the actual display code makes the code cleaner.